# Room database setup in Android Library module

Tags: android, android-room, android-library

I have an existing Android project in which I have created a new `Android Library` (offlineservicelibrary)(File/new/New module/Android library). In this library I want to create a room database.

I followed https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room and created Entity (OfflineData) and DAO(OfflineDataDao) setup for my database, but I am a bit confused about where to setup AppDatabase and how Link it to the library.

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(OfflineData::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getOfflineDataDao(): OfflineDataDao
}

val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
        ).build()
```

In my Library I do not have any class which extends Application class. Should I be creating a new class which extends Application class and do the above steps there.

Please suggest on what I should be doing to get the Library setup with Room database please

This is my Project structure with Library

[image]

Comment: You can make singleton in the library model, when other modules need a query database you should pass context to init your database if need.

Comment: Should I not be creating a class which extends Application?

Comment: Basically it still ok but what happen if another module needs context? so you can not make more custom Applications right?

Comment: can you give an example of how to do that please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make `DatabaseManager` Singleton class inside your module. Use `@JvmStatic` help you call from Java without `Companion`

```
class DatabaseManager private constructor(private val dp: AppDatabase) {
    fun loadData() : List<OfflineData> {
        return dp.getOfflineDataDao().loadAll() // I assume you already defined loadAll method in DAO
    }

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: DatabaseManager? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(context: Context): DatabaseManager {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: run {
                    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context,
                        AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
                    ).build()
                    DatabaseManager(db).also { INSTANCE = it }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. In other modules you need to use your database, you have to implementation `offlineservicelibrary` in `gradle` and pass context to it when call

```
DatabaseManager.getInstance(context).loadData()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this example, I cannot access getInstance method from my project. I am able to access DatabaseManager but not the getInstance method. @Cong Hai

Comment: And also should I be writing `DatabaseManager.getInstance(context).yourMethod()` this in presenter or Fragment, cuz presenter will not have context right

Comment: I tried it  from Fragment too and I could not access getInstance method

Comment: You mentioned a comment ` declare your function ...` what goes in there please?

Comment: aha this worked ` DatabaseManager.Companion.getInstance(getContext());`

Comment: Hai i did not quite understand `yourMethod()`  what will that be?

Comment: Haha, I think you know about kotlin because you use kotlin in your code. ok I will give more detail in example

Comment: Thank you so much for ur detailed answer, much appreciated. I did do it but was a bit different from your update. your updated answer was much better than what I did. :). I had another question actually on how to get the context within the android library, I have created a new question

Comment: Hai https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234384/how-to-get-the-context-within-the-android-library